# How do I apply transformations to groups in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of the form:

```
sym date       o     h     l     c     v           d sp ao       ah       al       ac       av         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A   1999.11.18 45.5  50    40    44    4.47399e+07 0 1  30.10473 33.08212 26.46569 29.11226 4.47399e+07
A   1999.11.19 42.94 43    39.81 40.38 1.08971e+07 0 1  28.41092 28.45062 26.33998 26.71712 1.08971e+07
A   1999.11.22 41.31 44    40.06 44    4705200     0 1  27.33244 29.11226 26.50539 29.11226 4705200
```

I'm trying to bring down the previous close down to today:

```
select sym, date, c, prev c from daily
```

but this doesn't respect the `sym` ticker groups. How do I apply this transformation at the ticker level?

Edit:
Also, is there a way that I can enforce a sort on `date` with this schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit messy, but is this roughly what you are looking for?

```
q)t: ([] sym: `a`b`a`b`a; date: 2021.01.01 2021.01.01 2021.01.02 2021.01.02 2021.01.03; c: 10 11 8 9 10)
q)t
sym date       c 
-----------------
a   2021.01.01 10
b   2021.01.01 11
a   2021.01.02 8 
b   2021.01.02 9 
a   2021.01.03 10
q)ungroup select date, c, prevClose: prev c by sym from `date xasc t
sym date       c  prevClose
---------------------------
a   2021.01.01 10          
a   2021.01.02 8  10       
a   2021.01.03 10 8        
b   2021.01.01 11          
b   2021.01.02 9  11
```

If not, could you give some example output?

Comment: Thanks! Is this the right representation for this? In numpy, I'd try to do it as 3-D matrix, ticker x date x value.